# How to Open the Image by clicking on the thumbnail in the order the image are saved in the NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

In my app i have thumbnail view and i want the user to go to the next view with the imageview and show the particular thumbnail clicked.But this image view is attached to the UIScroll with paging and UIPagecontrol. So i want the specific image to be open and at the specific index so that the user can swipe left or right to see other images.
This needs to be exactly like iPhoone's Photo app.

Please give me some link or tutorial to follow this. I can pass the index and open the particular image but just not able to set the image in order.

Thanks,

Comment: Yeah, please post some code. Is it the order of the files images in the DetailController thanks making trouble? What do you mean by "set the image in order".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ashutosh

I am sure following steps might be useful to you.

1] Pass the index of image clicked along with the entire data source (Array of images) to the detail screen.

2] Generate your scrollview with defined Rects for each image along with the paging.

3] Generate the rect for the previously selected index and make your scroll view to scroll to that specific rect, accordingly update your page control to show the desired page.

4] Make a method which will update the page control as user swipes through the scroll view image gallery and vice versa , i.e when page control is clicked update your scroll view.

Hope It helps!!

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little here is some code that will help you accomplish some of the steps suggested by @Rahul Sharma:

//You can first create an array that holds your images that will be in the UIScrollview. 
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"...],nil];

//In this example images is and array of UIImages and imgScroll is your UIScrollView
This will create the Scrollview with UIImageviews

```
 for (int i = 0; i < [images count]; i++){
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.imgScroll.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(self.imgScroll.frame.size.width, self.imgScroll.frame.size.height);

        UIImageView *subView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subView.image = [frames objectAtIndex:i];
        subView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.imgScroll addSubview:subView];
        [subView release];
    }

    self.imgScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.imgScroll.frame.size.width * images.count, self.imgScroll.frame.size.height);
    [self.imgScroll setDelegate:self];
```

Then call the delegate method to know when your imgScroll has scrolled

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Then using the index of the images array that you want to scroll to, you can 
calculate the offset of that UIImageView and set the scrollview to scroll
to that rect when the thumbnail is clicked.

```
[imgScroll scrollRectToVisible:imgToDisplay //This is a CGRect// animated:NO];
```

Hope this helps
Tams